# Authenticated Dev User Cannot WRITE/CREATE to CloudKit Public Database in Simulator

Tags: database, authentication, permissions, cloudkit, simulator

I have my device working on both a simulator and on my test iPhone. I want to save a new record to to the Cloudkit database. I can create records on the physical test device, but not in the simulator. When I submitted it for Apple's review they rejected it because of that as well. Both devices are signed into iCloud. This is confirmed right before saving the record with this code:

```
CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountStatus, error) in
        switch accountStatus {
        case .available:
            print("iCloud Available")
        case .noAccount:
            print("No iCloud account")
        case .restricted:
            print("iCloud restricted")
        case .couldNotDetermine:
            print("Unable to determine iCloud status")
        }
    }
```

The code I use to make the save is pretty straight forward and it works without any issues on real devices:

```
static func saveUser(user: UserElement, completion: @escaping (Result<UserElement, Error>) ->
    ()) {
    let itemRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "userInfo")
    
    itemRecord["uniqueID"] = user.bossID as CKRecordValue
    itemRecord["screenName"] = user.screenName as CKRecordValue
    itemRecord["shareCode"] = user.shareCode as CKRecordValue
    itemRecord["subscribedBosses"] = user.subscribedBosses as CKRecordValue

    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.Caz4Short.WatChaDoin")
    container.publicCloudDatabase.save(itemRecord) { (record, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                print("error on run")
                completion(.failure(err))
                return
            }
            
            guard let record = record else {
                print("record")
                completion(.failure(CloudKitHelperError.recordFailure))
                return
            }
            
            let id = record.recordID
            guard let boss = record["uniqueID"] as? String else {
                print("record ID")
                completion(.failure(CloudKitHelperError.recordIDFailure))
                return
            }
            guard let name = record["screenName"] as? String else {
                
                print("screenname")
                completion(.failure(CloudKitHelperError.castFailure))
                return
            }
            guard let bossCode = record["shareCode"] as? String else {
                print("Code")
                completion(.failure(CloudKitHelperError.castFailure))
                return
            }
            guard let subs = record["subscribedBosses"] as? [String] else {
                completion(.failure(CloudKitHelperError.castFailure))
                return
            }
            let element = UserElement(recordID: id, bossID: boss, screenName: name, shareCode: bossCode, subscribedBosses: subs)
            completion(.success(element))
        }
    }
}
```

The code fails at "Error On Run" with the resulting error message

> Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x9t83ecb31790; recordName=8AB667FA-0D8F-4B72-8B90-C694AB960EFF, zoneID=_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**> to server: CREATE operation not permitted

I get a similar error when I try to modify a record except it says WRITE instead of CREATE. I am able to read records without a problem though. This made me think I forgot to set the Security Roles for that zone, but that is not the case. Authenticated users &  have READ, CREATE, and WRITE selected for all zones. Creator also has READ and WRITE. I've also signed into iCloud on a computer and accepted the terms and conditions for the iCloud account a long time ago so its not like its a new account that needs to be setup. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated so it doesn't get rejected again!

[image: Image of Security Role Selections]

Comment: On the simulator, go to settings, then tap on the account name.  See if a password prompt comes up.  I've had a frequent issue, only on the simulator, where you end up in a 'partially logged into icloud' state.  The status checks return as if you are logged in, but saves/writes requiring you to be logged in fail.

Comment: Alternatively, I've seen an iCloud Drive issue before: go to Settings > your name > iCloud > iCloudDrive and confirm that is turned on.

Comment: No Luck. Everything says it is signed in. Including iCloud Drive. I even tried signing out and signing back in.

Comment: what error code is it giving?
                if let error = error as? CKError { print(error.errorCode) }

Comment: Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x9t83ecb31790; recordName=8AB667FA-0D8F-4B72-8B90-C694AB960EFF, zoneID=_defaultZone:defaultOwner> to server: CREATE operation not permitted

Comment: Sorry - but I'm looking for the cloudkit error code - that may help debugging - you have to cast the error as? CKError and then look at error.errorCode

Comment: Oh my mistake. I didn't know that was a thing. It returns "10".

Comment: CKErrorPermissionFailure  = 10, /* Access failure (save, fetch, or shareAccept) */
So it is something to do with the permissions rights...was wondering if it might be another issue

Comment: I'd test out permissions for 'world' in case the issue is that you aren't actually authenticated - just to see if there is something going on there.

Comment: World is only Read (can't be changed) so it definitely is acting like its not signed in, but it definitely is signed in.The code in the beginning even confirms that. I

Comment: All signs point to your device not being authenticated as a user and cloudkit applying 'World' permissions.  Last guess from my side - are you using the same icloud account on the device and simulator?

Comment: Good guess, but no I'm using my dev account on the simulator and my alt account on my iPhone. I don't know what accounts the Apple People are using. I filed a code level support ticket, but it look like they take weeks to finish.

Comment: I just realized that its not the physical device, its the alt account that works fine. When I installed the alt account on my simulator I was able to save records too. The dev account and apple tester accounts don't work.